# Helm swoop on all project files (not just current buffers)

Tags: buffers, helm

So I'm looking to have [`helm-swoop`](https://github.com/ShingoFukuyama/helm-swoop) look at *all* files in a project,
not just the current set of open buffers.

This is so I can use swoop to find all occurrences in a project, mark relevant ones, then edit them (in helm swoops edit mode).

I feel that there's probably a clean way to do this with Helm/Helm swoop
but here's my attempt to think through a solution:

1. gather filenames from projectile
2. create a list of buffers from the filename list
3. do the same routine as helm-multi-swoop-all besides using this new buffer list

`(projectile-current-project-files)`, looks like it gives me the file list I'm looking for.

So `helm-multi-swoop-all`, looks like it'd be fairly easy to copy and then tweak.

```
(defun helm-multi-swoop-all (&optional $query)
  (interactive)
  "Apply all buffers to helm-multi-swoop"
  (cond ($query
         (setq helm-multi-swoop-query $query))
        (mark-active
         (let (($st (buffer-substring-no-properties
                     (region-beginning) (region-end))))
           (if (string-match "\n" $st)
               (message "Multi line region is not allowed")
             (setq helm-multi-swoop-query
                   (helm-swoop-pre-input-optimize $st)))))
        ((setq helm-multi-swoop-query
               (helm-swoop-pre-input-optimize
                (funcall helm-swoop-pre-input-function))))
        (t (setq helm-multi-swoop-query "")))
  (helm-multi-swoop--exec nil
                          :$query helm-multi-swoop-query
                          :$buflist (helm-multi-swoop--get-buffer-list)))
```

Just replace the call to `helm-multi-swoop--get-buffer-list`,
to one that provided a list of buffers using projectiles list.

But now I'm a little stuck.
I'm not sure how to create a list of buffers to feed into helm-swoop from a set of file names.

I also can't help but think there's a simpler way to achieve this, maybe without custom functions.

Comment: This is potentially problematic. Suppose you want to swoop a large project for "abc". Do you want to open a file buffer for every single file you preview? You may well end up with ten or twenty extra buffers that you don't want. I'd suggest using `helm-projectile-ack` instead.

Comment: yeah, I wasn't imagining using this for a large project. I was also hoping to close the file buffers opened when finished with this routine.

Comment: Also, helm-projectile-ack (or ag) is nearly what I'm looking for, except I'd like to be able to edit the lines (like helm swoop allows)

Comment: I don't actually use `helm-swoop`. Does doing a `helm-projectile-grep` and then `F3` `M-x` `wgrep-mode` make it "editable"?

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of wgrep-mode. Helm-projectile-grep is picking up ignored files for me, but helm-projectile-ack is working well with wgrep. At least its working after uninstalling the wgrep that came from melpa, and using the one [here](https://github.com/mhayashi1120/Emacs-wgrep) instead.

Comment: At this point, I am unsure what you still want or need.

Comment: well, I'm still interested in an answer to the original question. Your suggestion works, but Helm swoop is a real nice interface, and I use it for other parts of my workflow. I'm still playing with my own implementation, but haven't gotten around to finishing it.

Comment: Ah. I see. Do you just want it to open a ton of file buffers and you can manually delete them later?

Comment: yeah, I've been messing with `find-file-noselect`. I can open the list of buffers fairly easily with `(mapcar 'find-file-noselect (projectile-current-project-files))`. But, as you said, it's pretty painful (they trigger all their hooks/modes). I was playing with using something like `(lambda(file) (find-file-noselect file nil t))` instead but... Helm swoop isn't reading those. Was going to read up on this stuff to see whats the minimum needed, then try it. I figure, if it runs fast enough on my medium sized projects, I can kill the buffers when I'm done fairly easily (just use the list I made)

Comment: `Helm Moccur` is your friend. It solves your issue.

Comment: @ReneFrogerjuh I haven't heard of helm moccur (I'm fairly new to emacs), [Is it this script?](https://github.com/myuhe/helm-c-moccur.el) Just reading the wiki, it looks like moccur works with opened buffers. I'm looking to search in all project files (even if they aren't currently in my buffers). Helm swoop already accommodates all buffer searching. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following the interesting comments from PythonNut, I installed [`helm-ag`](https://github.com/syohex/emacs-helm-ag), and ran `helm-projectile-ag` from the [projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile) package via `C-c p s s`. I then switched to editing mode with `C-c C-e`.  I changed a few lines and then pressed `C-c C-c` and these were saved to the relevant files.

**This works, but at present one infellicity is that it saves each of the "matched" files multiple times regardless of whether there was a change or not.  I raised this as [projectile #756](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/issues/756).**

Apart from that I think it would work well for the need mentioned in the question, and "without custom functions" :-)

Comment: this is actually what I've settled on as well. The only issue I'm having is that sometimes the files ignored by git/projectile aren't ignored in the ag search results. Haven't had the time to dig into it.

Comment: Tip: `helm-git-grep` should be faster than `helm-projectile-ag`

Comment: Why should it be faster?